# Where do I get the Windows SAPI .pdb file(s)?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, text-to-speech, sapi

I am looking for the .pdb files associated with Windows speech API 5. I've tried using the Microsoft symbol server at https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols but it does not download the SAPI pdbs, and following all the links to the Platform SDK but they are broken.

Can anyone help? I want to be able to know whats inside ISpObjectTokenCategory and other variables.

Comment: Not available.  You're not missing out on anything, ISpObjectTokenCategory is an interface and MSDL pdbs do not contain debugging info on their implementation.

Comment: @HansPassant In my experience, they usually do, such as in this case where it contains `CSpObjectTokenCategory::OpenKey`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the PDBs for the recent versions aren't available. I found an older version (5.3.13120.0) on a Windows 7 installation which the symbol servers had symbol files for.
The SHA-256 of that sapi.dll is

- x64 `e7c5f172bc194548bdb09cb6ba9d570cda559adf9cb634fdc2086884a26ea290`
- x86 `8ba490c65cb6978b4aaa8565a6e1f5277d90ecd3f08669712a26a3edda668e3d`

And here is the link ([x64](https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/sapi.pdb/B386CC0AEC6348D8BE5C733536962EB61/sapi.pdb)/[x86](https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/sapi.pdb/63C97D1D323C43A3844B09A0409498631/sapi.pdb)) to that file's PDB. Make sure to rename it to sapi.pdb.
There might be newer versions that also have their symbols available, but I haven't checked.